# React Native WebView video not playing in iOS

Tags: android, ios, react-native, video-player, react-native-webview

I developed mobile app which has video player in react native.
Then I built both Android and iOS app from the react native project.
But it's working well in Android but not playing in iOS.
If you've ever experienced this problem, please help me.

This is code and package information.

```
<WebView 
    allowsFullscreenVideo={true} 
    style={{ aspectRatio: 1.6, backgroundColor: "#000000", flex: 1 }}
    source={{ uri: 'https://sample.mp4' }}                    
/>

"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.5",
"react-native-webview": "^8.0.3",
```

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me in `android` and `ios`

```
<View style={{ height: 300 }}>
      <WebView
      style={{flex: 1.0}}
      javaScriptEnabled={true}
      domStorageEnabled={true}
      source={{uri: 'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4' }}/>
</View>
```